# Vite + vue + external sass module not triggering HMR for style changes

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs3, vite

I have a simple view in Vite + Vue + Sass. For styling i'm using external sass files for each component/view by using module ='classes' in the style tag and @use to use the specific scss file that should style the component/view. This doesen't trigger Vite HMR, I have to manually trigger a refresh in the browser for styles to change. HMR works just fine if I include the styles locally in the style tag, but it doesn't work with an external scss file. Here is an example:

```
<script setup>
import LogoNav from "@/components/navs/LogoNav.vue";
</script>

<template>
  <LogoNav />
  <main :class="classes.main">
    <div :class="classes.loader"></div>
  </main>
</template>

<style lang="scss" module="classes">
@use '@/sass/views/loading-profile';
</style>
```

My sass folder structure looks like this:

[image: sass folder structure]

Where im using the global scss files like abstracts, base and utilities in main.scss:

[image: main.scss]

And importing the main.scss file in main.js

[image]

Am I missing something crucial here? Have anyone encountered the same problem?